# The guy with the red shirt/with the red shirt on

Tags: word-usage

I was trying to say this to my friend and I get so confused. Which sentence is correct here?

> Can you see that guy with the red shirt?
>
> Can you see that guy with the red shirt on?
>
> Can you see that guy in the red shirt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All three versions are perfectly idiomatic, and mean ***exactly*** the same thing. Using ***a*** instead of ***the*** might be *slightly* more likely if the specific person being singled out wasn't the *only* person in view wearing a red shirt, but few native speakers would either express or recognise such a distinction in most contexts.

Comment: *With the red shirt* (not followed by *on*) could be interpreted to mean he is holding a red shirt rather than wearing one. *With the red shirt on* could conceivably be interpreted to mean something like *on his head*. In theory *in the red shirt* could mean *rolled up in the red shirt*. If you want to be very clear (since this seems to be about nit picking), I would use ***wearing*** *the red shirt*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Your comment would be a perfect answer.

Comment: “With the red shirt on” is something I’d say if I’m on a beach, and there are several guys, some wearing shirts, some holding them in their hands. Or I’d say “the guy in the red shirt” if someone else is carrying a red shirt in his hands. Very often no sentence is right or wrong, but they are for different situations.

Comment: All three of your examples are completely correct.   Use whichever you like.

Comment: @JasonBassford - It all depends who is actually wearing/carrying what. If the question refers to 3 guys, one wearing a red shirt and 2 wearing blue, saying "the guy with the red shirt" will indentify him unambiguously.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this sentence.

> Can you see that guy with the red shirt?

Also, you can use this sentence. You don't need to use the before in red.

> Can you see that guy in red?

You don't need to say "on" because when you use "with" it gives the meaning that he is wearing the red shirt.

> Can you see that guy with the red shirt on?

Comment: "You don't need to use the before in red" is ungrammatical and unclear.